# Word 2013 - protect a watermark only

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365

Is it possible to password protect a watermark on a word document? I have added one and now alls I want to do is prevent it from being removed.

I have found the protect document part, its just what to select

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Make the document read-only for your users. hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this however because it is set to read-only, then the user cannot edit text etc... if I unlock it then i'm back to square 1 where the user can remove it, I think with this its an issue that doesnt have an answer